# How do i write a log file in VC++ for a particular application?

Tags: visual-c++

How do i write a log file in VC++ for a particular application?

Comment: Suggest that this q needs clarification. Otherwise you may get a lot of "write it to the disk" answers.

Comment: any thing similar to java.util.logging

Comment: then log4cpp is your best bet.  If it's just a simple file you want, then there are many I/O runtime options for 'roll your own'.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own log method/class/library, like [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/logandtracefiles/article.php/c245) and [this](http://www.xiver.org/node/20) implementations

or use one third-party party log libraries.
[Log4cpp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/log4cpp/files/), for example.